# Distribution of $x_1 x_2+x_1 x_3$ with iid $x_i \sim N(0,1)$

Tags: normal-distribution, random-variable

Given are 3 independent standard normal variables $x_1,x_2,x_3$.

What is the pdf of $x_1 x_2+x_1 x_3$?

*What is known?*

The pdf of the product of two standard normal variables is the Bessel function $K_0(|x|)/\pi$.

Convolution cannot be applied as the summands are dependent.

Comment: Hint: For simplicity, use $X_1(X_2+X_3)$ where the second factor is $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu=0,\sigma=\sqrt{2})$ and factors are independent.

Comment: You can find the answer from https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/69134/when-is-the-distribution-of-product-of-two-normal-distributed-variables-near-nor